# purgue inactive queues using jmsTemplate

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to purge inactive queues in activeMQ

```
<amq:broker persistent="true" useJmx="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="1000">
    <amq:destinationPolicy>
        <amq:policyMap>
            <amq:policyEntries>
                <amq:policyEntry queue="queue.>" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="5000" />
            </amq:policyEntries>
        </amq:policyMap>
    </amq:destinationPolicy>
```

As I have read, a queue is inactive when have 0 messages and no new producers/consumers.

I am using jmsTemplate for sending process like this:

```
//Creates an org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory
conn = jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection(); 
session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
...
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, messageDTO);
....
session.close();
conn.close();
```

At the moment convertAndSend method is invoked, producer and queue are created, but when the sending has finished, producer is still alive (jconsole indicates producerCount=1) although I close session and connection so the queue is not purgued.

Why producer is not deleted?
Can affect to use cachingconnectingfactory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. 
You are seeing this behavior because of the default settings of CachingConnectionFactory, which is a

> SingleConnectionFactory subclass that adds Session caching as well
>   MessageProducer and consumer caching

As mentioned in the [spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html), **when close() is called on a cached session, it is not really closed but cached for reuse.**
The producers are also cached.

If you had used a SingleConnectionFactory you would have witnessed producer cleanup, but there are other things to consider before choosing the right connection factory.

If you want to use CachingConnectionFactory, you can disable producers from being cached by setting:

```
<property name="cacheProducers" value="false" />
```

You can do a similar setting for consumers as well.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Now queues are purged in a correct way. Very complete answer, really thanks!

Comment: If cacheProducers is set to false, by default JMSTemplate will create a new connection, session, producer for each message sent - then close them all down again. This is very inefficient!    The same scenario is applicable if cacheConsumers = false